# Visual Studio 2012 Image Library missing. Where to get one?

Tags: image, visual-studio, embedded-resource

The ***Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate (Update 1)*** is missing the Image Library zip contains a lot of default 
windows application icons in many useful formats and sizes.

In Visual Studio 2010 the file was in `\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip`, but there is no such file (**VS2012ImageLibrary.zip**) in new 2012 version.

What happens to that very popular (in my opinion) file? Is Microsoft going to attach the Library in Update 2? Or is it downloadable from different source?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ***download link*** for the latest **2012 Image Library** is: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825

Official Microsoft statement ([here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758881/image-library-missing-from-visual-studio-2012)) posted on 2012-11-30 is that they are going to attach 
that file in future update/release: "*We appreciate your patience while we worked on getting the release reviewed and approved internally.*".

I hope you all got what you need :)